# Error when comparing columns using >

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
     ci_inb_inv_id
    ,(item_seq_nbr*100)+94
    ,case when cor_val_txt > 0  then 'C'
          when cor_val_txt < 0  then 'A'
          else 'A'
      end
    ,item_seq_nbr
    ,cor_val_txt
    ,'DA'
    ,'O' 
    ,'O' 
    ,current_timestamp(0)
    ,user
```

this is the error i am getting

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying > integer
LINE 180: ,case when cor_val_txt > 0  then 'C'
```

Comment: The error is quite clear, `cor_val_txt` is defined as `character varying` so how can you compare it with an integer?

Comment: Postgres won't let you compar apples (strings) to oranges (integers). But the real question is: why are you storing numbers in a varchar column. That is a very bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare an integer with a string, PostgreSQL is strict and doesn't do any magic typecasting for you.

So I think you need to use `::` let `cor_val_txt` translate to `INTEGER` then compare.

```
SELECT
     ci_inb_inv_id
    ,(item_seq_nbr*100)+94
    ,case when cor_val_txt::INTEGER > 0  then 'C'
          when cor_val_txt::INTEGER < 0  then 'A'
          else 'A'
      end
    ,item_seq_nbr
    ,cor_val_txt
    ,'DA'
    ,'O' 
    ,'O' 
    ,current_timestamp(0)
    ,user
```